# Create table with Foreign Collection Field

Tags: java, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have this abstract class:

DomainItem

```
abstract public class DomainItem {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
        protected ForeignCollection<ContentItem> contentItens;

    //getters and setters
}
```

ContentItem:

```
abstract public class ContentItem {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected long id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    protected DomainItem domainItem;


    @DatabaseField()
    protected String content;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And these (no abstract):

```
@DatabaseTable()
public class PhytoterapicItem extends DomainItem{

    public PhytoterapicItem(){

    }

}
```

PhytoterapicContent

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "phytoterapiccontent")
public class PhytoterapicContent extends ContentItem {

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String defaultName;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String scientificName;

    //getters and setters
}
```

In my DatabaseHelper I trying create the tables:

```
//DatabaseHelper
...
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, PhytoterapicContent.class);
        Log.i(TAG, "Created table PhytoterapicContent");

        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, PhytoterapicItem.class);
        Log.i(TAG, "Created table PhytoterapicItem");
    catch{
       ...
    }
```

The table PhytoterapicContent is created. But I got the follow error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Foreign collection class br.com.project.model.ContentItem for field 'contentItens' column-name does not contain a foreign field of class br.com.project.model.PhytoterapicItem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the exception message was designed to help here.  To quote it with the class names removed:

> Foreign collection class `ContentItem` for field `contentItens` column-name does not contain a foreign field of class `PhytoterapicItem`

That looks to be the case.  Whenever you have `ForeignCollection`, the class contained by the collection *must* have a foreign field back to the parent class.

In your case, `PhytoterapicItem` extends the `DomainItem` class which has a `ForeignCollection` of `ContentItem` objects.  That means that `ContentItem` must have a foreign field of type `PhytoterapicItem`.  Otherwise, how would [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) know which of the `ContentItem` items in the table are associated with a particular `PhytoterapicItem`.

The example of `Account` and `Order` objects in the [foreign collection documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection) may help you with your schema.  Each `Account` has a foreign collection of `Order` objects.  Whenever you query for an `Account` a separate query is performed to find the collection of `Order` objects that correspond to a particular `Account`.  That means that each `Order` has to have a foreign `Account` object.

Comment: Works! I pulled out the relationships of abstract classes. Now they are in each 'Item' and respective 'Content' . Thx!!!

Answer (score 12):

It took me a while to notice/understand this critical block from the docs (http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection):

> Remember that when you have a ForeignCollection field, the class in the collection must (in this example Order) must have a foreign field for the class that has the collection (in this example Account). If Account has a foreign collection of Orders, then Order must have an Account foreign field. It is required so ORMLite can find the orders that match a particular account.

The reason I was confused is because I didn't find any example code (in docs or example projects) where the "contained class" references the class with the collection.  It is described verbally, but given the nature of the relationship - for some the description I think can be a bit tricky to follow when seeing it the first few times.

As listed above in the original question *(which is how I finally got the idea to try the solution I stumbled upon)*, the example block below **seems to be the correct way** to map a one-to-many collection relationship in OrmLite.

In addition, there is a note about how the collection-holder class needs to be set into the collection element class.

---

Here are the main steps to take care of:

A. In the class that has the collection *(**DomainItem** in this case)*, annotate collection field this way:

`@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)`

B. In the class that is contained in the collection *(**ContentItem** in this case)*, you must have an explicit reference back to the parent class that contains the collection:

`@DatabaseField(foreign = true) 
 protected DomainItem domainItem;`

C. Before persisting ContentItem, you must save the DomainItem to that ContentItem in order to set the foreign key back to DomainItem:

```
curContentItem.setDomainItem(curDomainItem);

contentItemDao.create(curContentItem);`
```

*I figured this out when my collection wasn't being retrieved initially.  I looked at the table for ContentItem, and the DomainItem_id was never set there.*

EXAMPLE:

```
public class DomainItem {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected long id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    protected ForeignCollection<ContentItem> contentItens;

    // ...
}


public class ContentItem {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected long id;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    protected DomainItem domainItem;

    public void setDomainItem(DomainItem domainItem) {

       this.domainItem = domainItem;
    }
}
```